# SonarQube time to persist issue

Tags: plsql, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Sonar LTS 5.6 with PL/SQL plugin.
I ran some scenario to identify the reason why some scans take a long time to complete.

I have an existing package source file with around 5'000 lines of code.

In below scenario I will generate issues to force Sonar scanner to commit in DB

### Scenario 1: (number of line of source file doesn't change)

I change a where clause at line 40 to duplicate a condition.

Original code :`where no_cli = p_no_cli`

New code : `where no_cli = p_no_cli and no_cli = p_no_cli`

Result : Scan is done in 6sec. (number of line of source file doesn't change)

### Scenario 2: (number of line of source file changes)

I change the same where clause at line 40 to duplicate a condition.

Original code :`where no_cli = p_no_cli`

New code : `where no_cli = p_no_cli 
              and no_cli = p_no_cli`

Result : Scan is done in 2 minutes!!. One line was added with new condition.

### Scenario 3: (number of line of source file changes)

I change a where clause at the end of file, at line 4976 to duplicate a condition.

Original code :`where no_cli = p_no_cli`

New code : `where no_cli = p_no_cli 
              and no_cli = p_no_cli`

Result : Scan is done in 6sec. One line was added with new condition.

My conclusion is when there are new issues and when number of lines of code change, if SonarQube need to re-index all the issues due to the new one (new issue is added at the beginning of the file), the scan take a long time to complete.

**I wonder if this can be due to the new feature of PL/SQL Plugin 3.0 that gives precise issue locations.**

**Edit on 15th May - Add screenshot**
[image]

First analysis
[image]

Second analysis
[image]

Comment: Did you use 3.0.1 (see [version matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix))?

Comment: Nop, I'm using 3.0.0.

Comment: The first analysis after switching to precise issue location (SonarPLSQL >= 3.0) requires much more time than usual because it updates all existing issues. All subsequent analyses should be back to normal. Can that explain what you see?

Comment: Sorry no. It is not a first analysis.
I had the issue you mentioned when I installed the new plugin version. But it was in October.

I forgot to say that for the file there are 500 issues detected by SonarQube.

Comment: Can you post the logs of the analysis? It should contain timestamps which can be helpful to understand the problem. The best thing to investigate would be a reproducer: a zip of a project where the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Where can I share with you the source file in private ?

Comment: @SebG check my profile

Comment: It does not seem related to SonarPLSQL itself.

Comment: Hey Sonar Team, I have more and more issue where analysis take age to persist new analysis when changes are done at the begin of a source code.
I redo the test I described and my conclusion is when issues need to be re-indexed the process take ages to persist.
Please could you have a look ?